# Google Maps Android: snap polyline to street

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Using Google Maps Android v2, how can I snap a route drawn with a polyline or just the points that are getting connected to a street?

I am getting locations from Google Play Services, but accurency is usually around 5-10 meters, so points are not directly on the street, but a bit wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this blog post guide I wrote on how to make a call to Google directions API parse the point and present them on Google Map:

[Google maps directions using Google Directions API and Polylines](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913233155/http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

Comment: yes, probably that's the way to go. However it seems this API is not a part of the Android framework or Google Play Services, so it won't work when the user is offline which is quite a bit of a downsite.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to ask [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for the exact path between two consecutive points returned to you as `Location` objects.

Example request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37,-96&destination=37,-96.1&sensor=false

Remember there is a limit of 2500 request per day per user (IP), so you may also want to limit your `LocationClient` or `LocationManager` updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the snapToRoads method provided by Google Roads API. You just need to provide the polyline LatLng points and it will return you a JSON file consist of polyline points that is snap more smoothly to the roads.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap